# How to calculate method execution time in c# while debugging in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I’ve a C# method written in Visual studio 2010 where several loop is executing. Now I want to calculate the method execution time while debugging.

I know that it is possible to calculate time using **Stopwatch** in my code but I am not authorized to change the code. So is there any way to calculate the method execution time while debugging?

Comment: use analog stopwatch. but your finger have to be really fast.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Have you tried it before like that?

Comment: VS 2015 will show the method execution. but not in VS 2010. Look at this image. put a breakpoint and press `F10`. it will show the time elapsed in end of next line http://i.stack.imgur.com/MtwjZ.png I was just kidding about using analog stopwatch

Comment: Use a profiler, like dotTrace or similar.

Comment: It is possible to show in VS2015 not in VS2010. Otherwise you can write a log file.

Answer (score 3):

Add breakpoints before and after the method execution.
Right click the breakpoints and choose **"When hit"**
In the dialog window, you can put in a print statement such as

```
"{DateTime.Now.Ticks}"
```

After both breakpoints are hit, you have timings before and after the method execution.

Please note that this will only have the precision of DateTime and will be affected by the debugging overhead. In case you want to do some real benchmarking, use specialized profilers instead.

Comment: Also, you can use `"{TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks).TotalSeconds}"` for converting it to seconds in the output.

Comment: In VS 2015 rt click on breakpoints > Actions > Log a message to output window and paste the timespan code there.